# can not add numbers to global variables from inside a function

Tags: python, function, global-variables, selection, subroutine

I am doing a project for a computer science NEA and I need to solve this problem, the problem being that global variables just won't work in the function. I'm probably being stupid but I'm not the best python programmer and it is really bugging me, it is a bunch of 'if' loops due to it being a selection algorithm, all help appreciated thanks!
The main issue is that it always adds 1 to 'c' no matter if i write something like 'warlike' where it should add 1 to 'd'
The bit of the code where issues are being had is down below or above, im not sure how this website works much, but the code is somewhere close to this message, looking forward to hearing from you all!

```
    c = int(0)
    csh = int(0)
    d = int(0)
    dsh = int(0)
    e = int(0)
    f = int(0)
    fsh = int(0)
    g = int(0)
    gsh = int(0)
    a = int(0)
    ash = int(0)
    b = int(0)

    def add_item(event=1):
      global list1
      global c
      global csh
      global d
      global dsh
      global e
      global f
      global fsh
      global g
      global gsh
      global a
      global ash
      global b
      if entry1.get() != "":
          listbox.insert(tk.END, entry1.get())
          #entry1.set("")
      if entry1 == "happy" or "cheerful" or "sunny" or "daytime":
        c = c + 1
      elif entry1 == "seldom" or "quaint" or "surly" or "discontent":
        csh = csh + 1
      elif entry1 == "triumphant" or "warlike" or "symphony" or "rejoice":
        d = d + 1
      elif entry1 == "love" or "god" or "heart" or "pop":
        dsh = dsh + 1
      elif entry1 == "joy" or "pleasure" or "laughter" or "delight":
        e = e + 1
      elif entry1 == "calm" or "complaisance" or "relaxing" or "soothing":
        f = f + 1
      elif entry1 == "relief" or "conquering" or "completeness" or "battle":
        fsh = fsh + 1
      elif entry1 == "rustic" or "idyllic" or "satisfying" or "tender":
        g = g + 1
      elif entry1 == "death" or "grave" or "dark" or "doom":
        gsh = gsh + 1
      elif entry1 == "innocence" or "affair" or "beloving" or "parting":
        a = a + 1
      elif entry1 == "cool" or "wild" or "bewildering" or "magestic":
        ash = ash + 1
      elif entry1 == "night" or "party" or "starry" or "galactic":
        b = b + 1
      entry1.delete(0, tk.END)
      list1.append(entry1.get())
```

Comment: You meant to write conditions like: `if entry1 in ["happy", "cheerful", "sunny", "daytime"]:`

Comment: what is the actual undesired behavior that you observe? ... `cannot add numbers` is probably your conclusion about the problem

Comment: the undersired behavior is that it always adds 1 to 'c', even if i write "warlike" which should be 'd'

Comment: That's because your first `if` condition is always true, as explained by the linked duplicate.

Comment: im confused do you know how i can fix this issue?

Comment: The first comment told you exactly how to fix it.

Comment: bad news, it sadly acts the same way, sorry guys :(

Comment: Then you did it wrong.  Remember that `entry1` is not a string.  It is a tk text box.  Here's a better way to handle this, by making it data-driven.  This also eliminates the global statements:  https://gist.github.com/timrprobocom/8279dad61af61508006343d939119910

Comment: that looks absolutely beautiful! thank you very much

Comment: is there also a way to print whichever one has the maximum number to it? i tried the 'max' function but it sadly isn't working